# About fractional Sobolev space

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading a paper used Sobolev space $H^s(\Omega)$ , I only know the definition of these space when $\Omega=R^n$ which used Fourier Transform, what if $\Omega$ is a bounded open set?

And I also want to know the bounded linear functional on this space look like?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You may find [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.2539v2.pdf) useful. It defines a fractional Sobolev space using the Laplacian operator and some functional calculus.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to take a look to this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345